# Android EditText Don't Call restartInput

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

I have an `EditText` that I empty after anything is typed into it (for whatever reason). I do this by calling `setText("")`

Everything works fine, unless the user is not on the default keyboard state (the number state for instance). Because `setText` calls `InputMethodManager.restartInput` after a key is pressed in the non-default state and I then call `setText("")`, `restartInput()` gets called, and the keyboard switches back to the default state (in most cases the "ABC" state).

This is very annoying if the user needs to type multiple numbers or special characters, etc... Is there any way to do this without `restartInput` getting called?

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing a `text watcher` on your edittext. In method `onTextChanged()`, you can use `setText("")`. You'll not have to deal with `ImputMethodManager` that way.

Comment: I'm already using a `TextWatcher` with `afterTextChanged` and I call `setText("")` in there. There are also places outside of the `TextWatcher` where I would need to call `setText("")` so that wouldn't work anyways.